# Story about a young man 'walking the feins'?

Tags: story-identification

I think I must be spelling this word 'feins' wrong, because I can not find it (or the variations of it I can think of) anywhere. It seems like it should be from some druid mythology or something. The novel was about priests of some sort who were also scribes... some of them had become corrupt. They would 'walk the feins' to gain powers. These feins were different points on a map (like a tree stump, a shed, a creek and a valley) that when walked in sequence would bestow some new skill to the walker. The corrupt ones were trying to find some ultimate path to walk to bring about a catastrophe or something. AND I'm not sure if I'm mixing up two stories, or if there are multiple storylines to follow in this book, but I seem to think that there is another man who is connected to a female elf and the two of them are being hunted by another elf.

I think that I read it in the 90's.

Comment: Perhaps the word is "veins", as in conduits for some sort of earth power. The concept also sounds similar to Ley lines: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ley_lines

Comment: Could the phrase have been 'walking the fens' ?  There's a list of authors that have used the 'Fens' as setting for their works.  I don't recognize any of the titles but you might browse and see if any ring a bell for you.  List is about 3/4 of the way down the page.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fens

Comment: It's not fens as in an area, it is more like the Ley lines idea in that it is like a connect-the-dots path that you walk 1, 2, 3, 4 and then some added power or enhanced sense is given to you.

Comment: I am quite interested to find out what this story is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am pretty sure this is The Kingdoms of Thorn and Bone series, by Greg Keyes (The Briar King, The Charnel Prince, The Blood Knight, The Born Queen).

People (generally only priests, because the church controls the fanes) can "walk the fanes" that relate to a particular saint and gain powers from that saint.

Comment: Thank you, I wouldn't have thought this was it! The story lines I remember about this series are totally different, mostly about Prince Robert and Princess Anne.

Comment: **Stephen's walking of the fanes takes place in [The Briar King](http://bit.ly/T1jTDU) and [The Born Queen](http://bit.ly/RCkrgl)**